# Seeking open source repository for composer packages, through which to proxy requests by my builds, and to build a local cache for future use

Tags: caching, proxy, composer-php

I am getting these sort of errors the past couple of days:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Ymd_apache2::Drupal::Install::Composer/Exec[composer_install_drupal_for-my.domain.tld]/returns:   
The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/icecave/parity%24e12bbae9986909655d8294143107cb751f4df60f2ac1f45e8254014c7873abd7.json" 
file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address
```

My question is this:  Does there exist an open source tool I could install in my cluster which would serve as a repository for composer (perhaps js as well) packages and which would proxy my requests to the outside world, caching successful pulls for required packages and preserving them for future deployments?

I am not budgeted for a jfrog license at this time.

So far, my research has found these two articles which seem relevant, but I am concerned that (1) so little seems to have been written about either of these; (2) so few commits seem have been offered to the repo, no releases are tagged; (3) its been many six some years since one of these articles was written.

Is either of these going to provide me a stable solution?  Or additional head-aches?

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-a-local-mirror-for-composer-packages-with-satis--net-36726

https://github.com/isaaceindhoven/velocita-proxy

Any relevant experience with these would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-- Hugh Esco

Comment: Which version of Composer are you using? Usually, it should download all data over HTTPS. And downloaded packages are served from a local cache - the given error message occurs one step before that, on downloading the package list.

Comment: On the other hand: have you checked why these errors occur? Does your cluster have any kind of network issue?

Comment: Pretty sure my network configuration is tight.  I have many other processes connecting from this cluster out to the world in multiple directions, without issue.  

My CI server has run perhaps 300 deployments using this process so far.  This is an intermittent issue, but it frustrated a handful of back-to-back deployments a couple of days ago.  Since then, deployments have succeeded (or sometimes failed for other reasons).  I have just identified this as a potential pain point to add to the backlog.  This question seeks guidance for a future enhancement to my cluster to address these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [satisfy](https://github.com/ludofleury/satisfy).

- provides composer repositories via satis
- has a web GUI
- can serve as a "cache" / proxy

We used it in a past project for similar purposes. Worked great.

It is well maintained by one of the greatest developers I ever had the pleasure to work with [@ramunasd](https://github.com/ramunasd).

You should be able to deploy satisfy into your cluster with ease.

Answer (score 1):

Developer of this project chiming in:

https://github.com/isaaceindhoven/velocita-proxy

The project is relatively new but more and more projects are starting to use it. Feel free to try it out, and if you run into anything make sure to raise an issue on GitHub. Heck, maybe even write a small article about it if it fit your needs? ;-)